# Mule logging outbound endpoint information

Tags: mule, interceptor, endpoint

Edit: Mule 3.3.1

I want to log the amount of time my flow spends waiting on an external service, plus some additional information about the call.  Right now, I'm doing that with a custom component that I declare globally:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="idAuth" class="com.ca.eai.esb.component.OutboundLogger">
        <spring:property name="calloutName" value="Authorization"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

and then invoke before and after my callout:

```
<component>
    <spring-object bean="idAuth"/>
</component>

<https:outbound-endpoint..../>

<component>
    <spring-object bean="idAuth"/>
</component>
```

It keeps track of time plus records some other facts.

My question is if there is a better way?  I'm thinking about how you can log before & after information about a flow by implementing an AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor and declaring it at the beginning of the flow.  Is there something analogous that you can implement and bind to the endpoint and have a method invoked on request and then another method invoked on response?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using MMC to deploy. You can use `Custom Business Events` Message processor.For that you have to enable even tracking in flow. So that in MMC under `Buiness Events` can see details about your flows and each and every message processor `Processing Time` and date and all other relavent information. knew it is in 3.2 version. Not sure about old version. you can check for that. 
Enable Events in flow: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Business+Events
Querying in MMC: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tracking+and+Querying+Business+Events

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it is a SOAP web service you are trying to hit.

You can use in-interceptor and out-interceptor combination in the Soap component endpoint to log the timings.

1)Create an in-interceptor and add a property variable(Say : inTime) to it containing the time
2)Create a out-interceptor where you will take the CurrentTime (minus) inTime to give you the time taken.
3)Log or display in the console the resultant time or any method for you to use the timing.

This would be an approach Which I would suggest.

If it is not a web service (Rather you need it only for the http endpoint)

1)Add a Global transformer for request, as Message properties, in the HTTP endpoint storing the time of calling
2)Another Global transformer for response, as Message properties, in the HTTP endpoint storing the time of response
3)Use another component (like logger with Groovy expression) to find the difference between the two time and display it